# Knockoutjs if binding with unmatched tags

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have an observable array, lets say `{ people: ko.observableArray() }` that I have bound to a series of divs

```
<!-- ko foreach: people -->
<div><span data-bind="text: name"></span></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Now I want to use a grid framework (specifically twitter bootstraps grid as it is already pervasive within the project) and start a new row every two items.  I've tried something like the following.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <!-- ko foreach: people -->
        <div class="span6"><span data-bind="text: name"></span></div>
        <!-- ko if: $index() % 2 === 1 -->
        </div><div class="row-fluid">
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Unfortunately knockout doesn't like the unmatched tags within the if statement and throws a binding error.  I could do the work in my view-model and split this up into an array of arrays but that feels wrong, if I were going to change to 3 per row I'd have to change both the view and the view-model.

I've set up this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3CVp/) as a starting point.

Is there anyway to get something like this working in the view alone?  Of course if there is a way to get bootstrap grids to wrap without the tag gymnastics that would also solve the problem.

Comment: Custom binding could solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/qgWLz/3/)

You don't need a raw binding.

```
<div class="container-fluid rb">
        <!-- ko foreach: people -->
        <!-- ko if: $index() % 2 === 0 -->
            <div class="row-fluid gb">
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: $index() % 2 === 1 -->
            </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <div class="span6 bb">
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        </div>

        <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the raw binding to fool KO. Its a bit of a hack, but works

http://jsfiddle.net/s3CVp/3/

```
<!-- ko if: $index() % 2 === 1 -->
    <!-- ko html: '</div><div class="row-fluid gb">' --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: This sounds exactly what I'm after, however there doesn't seem to be a raw binding.  It's a pretty easy binding to write myself but I want to check I'm not missing something first.

Comment: Its a built in binding in KO

Comment: I still can't seem to find it, has it maybe been dropped in recent versions?  The fiddle you provided also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: oh, sorry it is called "html", strange I thought I checked that the output of that fiddle was correct.  http://jsfiddle.net/Sd5HT/

Comment: Thanks Anders, the problem then is that the html binding is not allowed in virtual elements, which is a shame.